# Loop attribute of the element img

Tags: jquery, attr

when i try to get the value of a loop attribute of an image `<img src="myimag.png" loop="3" />`  the jQuery function returns **"loop**" but not the value.
It works fine with all others like:

```
var src = $(this).attr('src');
var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

[I did some digging](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L312) and apparently `loop` is a boolean attribute (`loop="loop"`). [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2) says:

> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., `selected="selected"`).

Here are the rest of those types of attributes:

```
rboolean = /^(?:autofocus|autoplay|async|checked|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped|selected)$/i;
```

jQuery takes these types of attributes into account and returns the proper attribute value, regardless of the actual value of the attribute. If the attribute is present, it is set to "true".

---

If you want to store data in HTML elements, use `data-` attributes:

```
<img src="myimag.png" data-loop="3" />
```

Now, `$('img').data('loop')` returns the *number* `3`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug of jQuery.

The native method give you the right value.

```
console.log($('img')[0].attributes.getNamedItem('loop').nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`loop` is a boolean attribute.  jQuery will return the name of the attribute itself for boolean attributes (i.e. this would happen for `disabled` as well.  `loop` is also no longer in the HTML spec (http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes) so you shouldn't use it.

I'm not clear on what the *purpose* of your use of it is either.  Seems like you should probably be using `data-loop` instead.  Then you can access it normally with either `.attr('data-loop')` or `.data('loop')`.